# Android TransitionDrawable change Imageview background and foreground?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, transition

I have an ImageView with a TransitionDrawable background which works fine. What I would like to do is also to change the image inside the ImageView with the same transition applied. 
Or what would be the approach to change the background and foreground of an Imageview with a fade in effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a try:

Can you hve an ImageView with a TransitionDrawable background and a transparent foreground(`alpha=0`)

And inside this ImageView add a child (also an `ImageView`) with a TransitionDrawable background and a transparent foreground.

I am guessing that the first ImageView's TransitionDrawable background will be the backround of the overall,
 and the second ImageView's TransitionDrawable background will be the foreground of the overall.